# $f(x,y) =\min\{2, |x-y| \}$ for $f(x,y) \leq f(x,z) + f(z,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

If we have a function: $f(x,y) =\min\{2, |x-y| \}$

Why does the following hold?

$$f(x,y) \leq f(x,z) + f(z,y)$$

I see that it holds if $|x-z| \geq 2$ and $|z- y| \geq 2 $

But I don't know about other posibilites. Can somebody please explain.

It should hold for every $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Note that |x-y| $\le$ |x-z|+|y-z|.  Otjer cases are direct.

Comment: @herbsteinberg The case where I don't understand mostly is for: $|x-z |< 2$ and $|z-y|<2$

Comment: @VLC: if $0<a,b$ and a $a+b<2$ then $a,b<2$ and ($g$ as in my hint) $g(a+b)=a+b=g(a)+g(b)$. Notice that $f(x,y)=g(|x-y|)$ where $g$ is as in my hint. Thus, with $a=|x-z|$ and $b=|z-y|$, $f(x,y)=g(|x-y|)\leq g(|x-z|+|z-y|)=g(a+b)=g(a)+g(b)=f(x,z)+f(z,y)$.

Comment: @VLC $min(2,|x-y|)\le |x-y|\le |x-z|+|y-z|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $f(x,y)=g(|x-y|)$ where  $g(a)=\min(2,a)$. Then, it suffices to check $(why?)$ that $g$ is nondecreasing and sub additive on $[0,\infty)$, that is $g(a)\leq g(b)$ if $a<b$ and
$$g(a+b)\leq g(a)+g(b), \qquad a,b\geq0$$

The first condition is trivial; the second is not complicated to check.

---

**Comment:** In general, if $(X,d)$ isa metric space and $G:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is a function such that $G(x)=0$ iff $x=0$, $G$ is continuous monotone nondecreasing, and $G$ is subadditive, then $D(x,y)=G(d(x,y))$ defines a metric in $X$ equivalent to $d$ (in particular, the triangle inequality holds, that is $D(x,y)\leq D(x,z)+D(z,y)$ for all $x,y,z\in X$).